# projector issues with Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, projector

A fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 on HP Pavilion m6. When I hook up a projector or second monitor to this laptop, the display defaults to the second monitor or projector and shuts down the main display. The only window I can open on the second monitor is the terminal and nautilus. I suspect that other apps are attempting to display on the main screen, but nothing is showing. I cannot adjust the monitor settings using the GUI and I'm not familiar enough with terminal to be able to turn the main display back on. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, try

```
unity-control-center
```

From there you want the "Display" options. From there you should be able to set up mirrored display, extended display, whatever you like.

This launches the usual system settings dialog. Usually this is easy to get to via the Unity launcher in the top left, or from the Super key. Then you would search "Settings" or "Display."

Comment: That got me into the display options, when I chose mirror displays, it moved the display to the main display, I let it revert to previous settings and it shutdown both displays. I had to do a hard restart to get back to one display functioning. I now have the display staying on the main display with the second monitor attached, but I cannot get anything to display on the second monitor.

Comment: Hmm. Applying mirrored displays works just fine for me. I'm using VGA video out with Ubuntu 14.04. What if you don't use mirrored, but change the option for using the built-in display?
// 
Something else to try is Additional Drivers (also in unity-control-center). This lets you install the vendor's proprietary drivers. Either choose the latest or stable version. Updating graphics drivers usually requires a full reboot, then you can test your workflow again.

Comment: With mirrored displays enabled, I can use the F4 key to move from one display to the other, but can't seem to get both to work at the same time. With mirrored displays disabled I can now drag files, windows off the functioning display, but they disappear out of sight, I can click on them (blind) and drag them back but still nothing shows on the second screen. They are both showing as enabled in the 'screen display' window.

Comment: Proprietary display drivers was the ticket to success!  Thanks nshiff!

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. I'm still trying to collect reputation points,  so feel free to vote up and accept my answer. :)

Comment: Happy to do that....how?